# File tabs on distraction free mode on Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

How do I show the file tabs in the distraction free mode of Sublime Text 2? What should I add in my `Distraction Free.sublime-settings`?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you move the mouse in the upper side of the screen, you can access the menu.

In `View` you can select `Show Tabs`

[image: Show Tabs]

The setting will be remembered next time you enter distraction free mode.

`Distraction Free.sublime-settings` does not seem to be meant for UI chrome settings.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize it was that simple. I'm also not aware with the term "UI Chrome settings". Thank you!

Comment: UI chrome is a way to refer to the graphical features of an application (buttons, checkbox, elements like those...). Probably it's a bit slangy :)